# Product of Baire sigma-algebras

Tags: descriptive-set-theory, measure-theory

Suppose that $X$ is a Polish space and $\mathcal{E}$ is the $\sigma $-algebra of subsets of $X$ with the property of Baire. Consider the product $\sigma $-algebra $\mathcal{E}\otimes \mathcal{E}$ on $X\times X$, which is
the coarsest $\sigma $-algebra on $X\times X$ making the canonical
projections $\mathcal{E}$-measurable.

QUESTION: Is it true that $\mathcal{E}\otimes 
\mathcal{E}$ contains all meager subsets of $X\times X$? (This would imply
that $\mathcal{E}\otimes \mathcal{E}$ coincides with the $\sigma $-algebra
of subsets of $X\times X$ with the property of Baire.)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that $X$ is an uncountable Polish space, the desired conclusion that $\mathcal{E} \otimes \mathcal{E}$ contains all sets with the property of Baire is not true. In fact, [analytic sets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_set) have the property of Baire and it is a variant of a result due to Mansfield and Rao that no universal analytic set belongs to $\mathcal{E} \otimes \mathcal{E}$. See Miller, [Measurable rectangles](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9211206), Theorem 1 for a proof of this. In my answer to a [related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/177416) on math.SE there are more explanations and further references.

Comment: NB: this also tells us how to find a meager set that doesn't belong to $\mathcal{E} \otimes \mathcal{E}$: take a universal analytic set $A$ in $X \times X$ and take an open set $U$ such that $M = A \mathbin{\Delta} U$ is meager. Then $M \notin \mathcal{E} \otimes \mathcal{E}$.